# Button in Android does not have text centered

Tags: android, android-layout

I made oval `Button` with shadow around, but my text inside this `Button` is not centered. Text is still at the bottom for some reason. Any solutions?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/set_btn"
    style="@style/button.shadow.oval"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="-"
    android:textColor="@color/ceruleanBlue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_mid_large"
    android:tint="?attr/textColorPrimary"/>

<style name="button.shadow.oval">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/button_oval_small</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_oval_small</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_shadow</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@null</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">@null</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
</style>
```

But text looks like this(minus should be centered). This glitch is only visible to characters like `- + * =`. Other characters are slightly off centered but it looks alright.

[image]

Comment: Just add `android:gravity="center"` to your XML button

Comment: I tried that, nothing has changed.

Comment: Change `android:text="-"` to `android:text="﹣"` if you want to more symbol : https://coolsymbol.com/pi-symbol-infinity-symbol-sum-sigma-symbol-square-root-symbol-integral-symbol-math-signs.html

Answer (score 0):

you can simple use `<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>` for floating button